# Filter by "My watched tags" only respects the first 50 of them

Tags: feature-request

I'm not sure if this is the right place.

I just noticed that it only picks the first 50 (alphabetically) of my watched tags, so I missed questions in tags I'm interested in.

I'd like the limit for this feature to be raised.

A workaround would be to bookmark a query literally mentioning every tag I'm watching but that won't update on its own if my interests expand to another tag.

Comment: Create a custom filter instead. It handles more tags  than what the search does.

Comment: That seems like a lot for one filter. Couldn't you break them up by subject into several filters?

Comment: it's mostly niche low-traffic tags. sure I could split that up and maintain multiple bookmarks, but then the "watched tags" feature itself becomes useless to me. I haven't actually checked whether a single query of specific tags has a limitation or not. I only know the "my watched tags" option ends at 50 watched tags.

Comment: With watched tags, you'll still get the highlight of questions that have one of those on it. Except in the case you've searched for those tags - if you watched tag [a] and [b], searched for [a] - then the highlighting in the list only applies for [b].

Comment: At any rate, you don't need browser bookmarks if you create custom filters. Again, though, the custom filter should be able to handle more than that - the main one I use has 59 tags in it.